# Calling API in loop

Tags: arrays, api, recursion

I am struggling with my code. Case is i need to fetch all issues form JIRA for particular user.

API is constructed like pagination so it only return max 1000 results in one call
I my case now i have 11588 issues.

```
{ expand: 'schema,names',
  startAt: 0,
  maxResults: 1000,
  total: 11855,
  issues:[......]
}
```

the second call will retrive

```
 { expand: 'schema,names',
      startAt: 1000,
      maxResults: 1000,
      total: 11855,
      issues:[......]
    }
```

and so on...

so in each iteration i am adding 1000 to `startAt` and as long as `issues` array i not empty keep the loop

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");
var util = require("util");
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);

const limitPerPage = 1000;
const apiUrl =
  "http://localhost:8080/rest/arest/1.0/search?";

const getIssues = async function(startAt = 1) {
  try {
    var options = {
      method: "GET",
      url:
        apiUrl +
        `jql=assignee=ironman&startAt=${startAt}&maxResults=${limitPerPage}`,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    };

    let res = await requestPromise(options);
    let JSONData = JSON.parse(res.body);
    return JSONData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

};

const getAllIssues = async function(startAt = 1) {
  try {
    const results = await getIssues(startAt);
    console.log("Retreiving data from API for page : " + startAt);

    if (results.issues.length > 0) {
      return results.concat(await getAllIssues(startAt + 1000));
    } else if (results.issues.length == 0) {
      return results;
    }  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

};

(async () => {
  try {
    const entireList = await getAllIssues();
  console.log(entireList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

})();
```

and the issue is at the end is not returning all results

```
TypeError: results.concat is not a function
```

also log from console when it is running:

```
Retreiving data from API for page : 1
Retreiving data from API for page : 1001
Retreiving data from API for page : 2001
Retreiving data from API for page : 3001
Retreiving data from API for page : 4001
Retreiving data from API for page : 5001
Retreiving data from API for page : 6001
Retreiving data from API for page : 7001
Retreiving data from API for page : 8001
Retreiving data from API for page : 9001
Retreiving data from API for page : 10001
Retreiving data from API for page : 11001
Retreiving data from API for page : 12001
TypeError: results.concat is not a function
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call `getIssues` instead of `getAllIssues` when calling `concat`?

Comment: if i call getIssues i will only get result from one call and that; it. concat to append result from each iteraiton

Comment: `TypeError: results.concat is not a function`: I don't know this language, but the error message seems pretty clear to me. Are you sure that you try to call the right method on the right object which has the right type ?

Comment: yes i think it error mean that array that program want to append is empty